# "geodesic" subgraph of a directed graph

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have a directed, acyclic graph G.  The underlying graph is actually a complete graph.  I would like to create a subgraph where the non-geodesic paths of length two are removed.  So, given a triangle of edges in G a->b, b->c, and a->c, I would like to remove a-> b and b->c.  Is there a package in Python which will do this?

Comment: It's not completely clear what paths of length 2 should be removed. In your example, the path `a->b` has the length of 1, not 2 - if we consider `b` as the target vertex. Why would you remove it then? Then, with a path `a->b->c->d`, the resulting graph is not deterministic - it depends on the order of removal. What are the criteria to choose one option over another?

Comment: Good point.  I was curious whether there was some sort of standard reduction, analogous to a minimal spanning tree.  In the case I am interested in, I actually have a ranking of vertices, and I want to choose the surviving edges to have the largest possible distance according to this ranking.  I.e.  I would like to maximize the sum of rank(j) - rank(i) over all remaining edges.  I coded something up with a simple greedy algorithm which I think is optimal.  It can be translated to a linear programming problem too.  But I thought perhaps this sort of problem was well studied in some context.